# Version revert causing inaccurate information to be retrieved during first flow run subsequent to the revert

Tags: calculated-column, power-automate

I am not sure if this is a legitimate question since I am more like reporting what I think is a legitimate issue, but I recently seem to be seeing that reverting to a version of a flow will prompt it to actually overwrite some of the calculated column values to old values (my calculated column is date dependent), which then cause flow to pull the wrong data (or at least, I felt like calculated columns should provide values based on the runtime of the query). I still need to research more about it, but I am seeing if anybody has encountered something similar.

See below for the flow run on the left. Get items's output has been shown on the right with the JSON code. I have moved it to item 16 as shown and the "ES" compose field was a simply retrieval of the EScore field. You can clearly see that the field is different from the value that is provided when you navigate to the sharepoint site itself in the middle. The flow on the left syncs the EScoreTotal field with EScore basically, hence you can see that the EScore total on the sharepoint page is different from the ones retrieved from flow and the JSON results.

The funny thing is, when I checked the version that was supposed to match the data when the flow was run, you can see that the EScore values are actually different from any of these numbers shown here (i.e. access updated the values to the correct ones). And I reverted versions last night, so my theory is that when you have formulas that are time dependent, it actually will cause bugs because calculated columns do not re-calculate at query runtime, but rather, only at access run time. That resulted in inaccurate results with flow.

[image: Data records]

Answer (score 0):

When reverting versions, it will be probably be beneficial to access the page to ensure things update properly before running flows accordingly to ensure calculated column data has been updated to the correct values.